Openstack kolla create instance network error
I tried to create an instance and just when the IP from the selected network should be assigned to the instance, it fails. Of course, an IP is given, but it seems that it cannot create the interface and assign it inside the machine (I have built machines in vmware ESXI(nic type vmxnet 3 on vmware) and configured with kolla ansible multi node)
Does anyone have any ideas ?

fault | {'code': 500, 'created': '2024-05-14T12:31:44Z', 'message': 'Build of instance 96447a00-8068-4f8d-86a2-d844775666d7 aborted: 

Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.', 'details': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 8006, in _create_guest_with_network\n with self.virtapi.wait_for_instance_event(\n File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 142, in exit\n next(self.gen)\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 559, in wait_for_instance_event\n self._wait_for_instance_events(\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 471, in _wait_for_instance_events\n actual_event = event.wait()\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 436, in wait\n instance_event = self.event.wait()\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 124, in wait\n result = hub.switch()\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 310, in switch\n return self.greenlet.switch()\neventlet.timeout.Timeout: 300 seconds\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2632, in _build_and_run_instance\n self.driver.spawn(context, instance, image_meta,\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4646, in spawn\n self._create_guest_with_network(\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 8032, in _create_guest_with_network\n raise exception.VirtualInterfaceCreateException()\nnova.exception.VirtualInterfaceCreateException: Virtual Interface creation failed\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2447, in _do_build_and_run_instance\n self._build_and_run_instance(context, instance, image,\n File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2696, in _build_and_run_instance\n raise exception.BuildAbortException(instance_uuid=instance.uuid,\nnova.exception.BuildAbortException: Build of instance 96447a00-8068-4f8d-86a2-d844775666d7 aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.\n'} | | flavor | mini-01 (c4389879-f009-4ade-825b-757960228f94)

openstack server create
--image cirros-0.6.2
--flavor mini-01
--network nw-local-10.10
Test1 

I followed the process of creating a server. Its interface is built on compute, but it seems that it cannot inject the dhcp network and it fails
root@lab-compute-01:/var/log/kolla/openvswitch# tail -f ovs-vswitchd.log 
2024-05-15T12:45:11.364Z|00050|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: added interface tapf87464a7-24 on port 4
2024-05-15T12:45:11.373Z|00051|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: deleted interface tapf87464a7-24 on port 4
2024-05-15T12:45:11.379Z|00052|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tapf87464a7-24 (No such device)
2024-05-15T12:57:33.216Z|00053|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tap1db4b6b1-c2 (No such device)
2024-05-15T12:57:33.356Z|00054|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: added interface tap1db4b6b1-c2 on port 5
2024-05-15T13:02:34.233Z|00055|bridge|INFO|bridge br-int: deleted interface tap1db4b6b1-c2 on port 5
2024-05-15T13:02:34.241Z|00056|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tap1db4b6b1-c2 (No such device)
2024-05-15T13:02:34.251Z|00057|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tap1db4b6b1-c2 (No such device)
2024-05-15T13:02:34.415Z|00058|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tap1db4b6b1-c2 (No such device)
2024-05-15T13:02:34.424Z|00059|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tap1db4b6b1-c2 (No such device)


you should give your network name/id in --network switch. you can list it with "openstack network list" and create your instance with it.

the --network 10.0.0.0/24 is one name like subnet .
